# Uniqueness of pseudoinverse?

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

Recently, I read a line of reasoning as

> Since $A$ (a $3\times 3$ matrix) is of rank $2$, its pseudoinverse is not unique.

May I ask if there is a quickie to show this?

Comment: How do they define pseudoinverse? The [Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) is unique for every matrix.

Comment: @2mkgz Forgive my ignorance, I am not sure the name, but through that article, they define pseudoinverse as $A=UDV^T, A^+=VD^+U^T$.

Comment: ...where $U$, $D$, and $V$ are.... ?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Sorry, where $U, D, V$ are the SVD of $A$

Comment: @SibbsGambling Alright, so $A^+$ is *the* Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse which is unique for any matrix (nevertheless, there exist other generalized inverses which might be non-unique).

Answer (score 6):

As noted by @Algebraic Pavel, the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is unique. Perhaps you are thinking of the least squares solution to the problem
$$
 \mathbf{A} x = b.
$$
The column rank defect indicates that the null space $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A})$ is not trivial. The least squares minimizers, defined as
$$
  x_{LS} = \text{arg}\!\min\limits_{x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}} \lVert \mathbf{A} x - b \rVert_{2}^{2}
$$
are an affine space given by
$$
 x_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b + \left(
  \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A}
\right) y, \quad y \in\mathbb{C}^{n}.
$$
The arbitrary vector $y$ demonstrates the infinitude of solutions. That is when the matrix rank is less than the number of columns, the least squares solution is not unique.

So in the case of column rank defect the pseudoinverse solution is the point where the affine space of minimizers intersects $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}^{*})$.